# How can add Check box when binding Data to data table?

Tags: jquery, razor, datatable

I want to add check box in Data table when Data is binding to Data table

i will share my code here

im using Jquery Datatble here and im using C# and razor,

```
function BindColumSelectTable(DataExchangeList) {
    debugger
    $('#columnSelectTable').DataTable({      
        "data": DataExchangeList,
        "destroy": true,
        "columns": [
            { data: null },
            { data:"FieldCaption" },
        ],
        "columnDefs": [
            { className: "checkbox i-checks", "targets": [0] },
            { className:"tabletdAdjust","targets":[1]}
        ],     
    });
}
```

Im expecting a result like a table with two columns. *First Column is for **check box** and the second column is the data bind from the list.* 
Now i get **objectobject** for the first column

this is the output now i get

```
Column          Name
[objectObject] ID
[objectObject] Code
[objectObject] Name
[objectObject] CreatedBy
[objectObject] CreatedDate
[objectObject] UpdatedBy
[objectObject] UpdatedDate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [a similar issue](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/43457/index-column-prints-object-object#Comment_114201), I think the problem is caused by usage of `data: null` definition as the first column. It tells `DataTables` to use original object for corresponding row as data source for that column.

You should set `data` setting with non-existent property name in data source and use `defaultContent` option if you don't have unique ID column in table:

```
{ data: 'id', defaultContent: '' }
```

so that the column definition should be look like this:

```
"columns": [
    { data: 'id', defaultContent: '' }
    { data: 'FieldCaption' },
],
```

As for using select checkboxes, you can set `columnDefs` like this (see [the reference](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/checkbox.html) for example):

```
columnDefs: [{
    orderable: false,
    className: 'select-checkbox i-checks',
    targets: 0
},
{ 
    className: 'tabletdAdjust',
    targets: 1
}],
```

Answer (score 0):

we can simply do one thing to add check box with data

```
"columns": [
        {
            data: 'check', defaultContent: '', render: function (data, type, row) {
                return '<input type="checkbox"/>'
            }
        },
        { data:"FieldCaption" },
    ],
```

only we need to add a render function and return a check box